# Is it possible to secure .net framework webapi with identity server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, .net-framework-version

I have created identity server4 implementation which is working fine with. Net core api. I also have a old .net framework api and I want to secure that using identity server4. How to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using IdentityServer's Katana Access Token Validation Middleware named `IdentitySever3.AccessTokenValidation` on the API.
I have a detailed blog post with sample code for it:
https://nahidfa.com/posts/identityserver4-and-asp-.net-web-api/

Comment: I tried your blog but could not accomplish if I use [Authorize] attribute.  I have created another question [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67328905/netframework-api-owin-identityserver3-accesstokenvalidation-can-not-access-aut , Can you help me on this

Comment: I downloaded the repo but could not run. The problem is identity server could not redirect. I debug the login user and in accountController line 148 , the redirect URL not working. I mean not redirecting still at login page. No redirect is working. Even login from the identity server main page while clicking grant , its also not redirecting

Comment: Thanks for the blog. In Identity server we have to change the AccessTokenJwtType to "JWT," default returning ad "jwt + at" , what is the difference between these

Comment: for redirect issue, do you have self signed https setup?

Comment: about access token type, tas you mentioned he default on IdentityServer4 is `jwt + at`. Its the recommended value by OAuth best practices. `at` stands for access token. This helps  for example to recognize access token vs identity token via type as well. But .NET 4.* libraries for JWT are not compatible with it and as I explained in my blog you should change the type to `jwt`